# http:// website listed as https:// in search results

Tags: http, redirect, https

I have a Wordpress website that is being listed in Google results as a https:// website. Thing is that I have not set up a SSL or https:// for this website.

I've searched online and some people suggested that I might have https:// links inside my website and indeed there were some. However, after doing this modifications the website result still directs to a https:// address

Is there any other way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https will by default connect to port 443. You can then send a redirect (if possible) from your webserver from port 443 to the client to go the http on port 80 instead. I think that you have to send a redirect to the client. Making port 443 redirect directly to port 80 in your webserver's configuration may not remove the encryption and cause some issues